Adding specific values from one dataframe into another
I have two separate data frames, where I'd like to add specific columns from the second data frame to the first one but I want their values to match specific rows in the first one, mainly whenever its says 'red' in the 'descriptor' column and also match for 'date' and 'product'.
Data frame 1:
date   product    descriptor        
jan    product1   blue
feb    product2   green
mar    product1   red
apr    product2   blue
may    product1   red       
jun    product2   red        

Data frame 2:
date   product    val        
mar    product1   x
may    product1   y
jun    product2   z

I want to achieve something like this:
date   product    descriptor  val       
jan    product1   blue
feb    product2   green
mar    product1   red          x
apr    product2   blue
may    product1   red          y
jun    product2   red          z

I've tried looking for something similar but couldn't find anything that exactly matches my question.

out = df1.merge(df2, how='left')

Not quite, I just realized you want to limit the output to descriptor that are red. I'll reopen.

Note that your example is ambiguous, there is no case in which a non-red value would have a non-null value assigned with a normal merge.

You can merge, mask and combine_first:
out = df1.combine_first(df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(['date', 'product']),
                                  on=['date', 'product'], how='left')
                           .where(df1['descriptor'].eq('red'))
                       )

Or, align with a MultiIndex:
cols = ['date', 'product']

df1.loc[m, ['val']] = (df2.set_index(cols)
                          .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1[cols]))
                          .set_axis(df1.index)
                          .where(df1['descriptor'].eq('red'))
                      )

Or perform a classical merge, then fix the values:
out = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
out.loc[df1['descriptor'].ne('red'), ['val']] = float('nan')

Output:
  date descriptor   product  val
0  jan       blue  product1  NaN
1  feb      green  product2  NaN
2  mar        red  product1    x
3  apr       blue  product2  NaN
4  may        red  product1    y
5  jun        red  product2    z


Worked, perfectly thank you

import pandas as pd

# DataFrame 1
data1 = {
    'date': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun'],
    'product': ['product1', 'product2', 'product1', 'product2', 'product1', 'product2'],
    'descriptor': ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'red']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# DataFrame 2
data2 = {
    'date': ['mar', 'may', 'jun'],
    'product': ['product1', 'product1', 'product2'],
    'val': ['x', 'y', 'z']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_combined = df1.merge(df2, on = ['date','product'], how = 'left' )
print(df_combined)
df_combined['val'] = df_combined.apply(
lambda row : row['val'] if row['descriptor'] == 'red' else 'not_red',axis=1   
)
print(df_combined)
'''
  date   product descriptor      val
0  jan  product1       blue  not_red
1  feb  product2      green  not_red
2  mar  product1        red        x
3  apr  product2       blue  not_red
4  may  product1        red        y
5  jun  product2        red        z
'''

